# Retrieving return value from WCF application

Tags: c#, wcf, datagrid

I am trying to select the `Id` of the **last** row of data that was entered into my `Quote` table and then display all of the information related to that `Id` in my WPF application's datagrid.

Here is my coding in my **WCF** application where I *hope* to get the `Id`:

```
public Quote GetLastQuote()
{
    using (TruckDb db = new TruckDb())
    {
        var quote = (from qData in db.Quotes
                     orderby qData.Id descending
                     select qData).First();
        return quote;
    }
}
```

Now after I get the `Id` I wan't my **WPF** application to handle the Id's information and then display it in a `datagrid`. Here is my coding in my WPF application:

```
private async void wListOfBills_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (TruckServiceClient client = new TruckServiceClient())
    {
        var quoteLast = await client.GetLastQuoteAsync(); // --> My error
        var bills = await client.GetListOfBillsAsync(quoteLast.Id);

        dgFloor.ItemsSource = bills.Select(x => new ListOfBillsView
        {
            Code = x.StockCode,
            Group = x.GroupName,
            ...
            Section = x.Section
        }).ToList();
    }
}
```

My application builds fine until I access my `datagrid` and then the **WPF** application crashes with the following error:

> Additional information: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP
>   response to http://localhost:xxxxxx/xxx.svc. This could be due to the
>   service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also
>   be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server
>   (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more
>   details.

I also data binded all the columns of the `datagrid` to the `ListOfBillsView` class, but I can't seem to get past the error that I received above.

This is my datagrid's **XAML** binding:

```
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Code}" Header="Code" MinWidth="100" MaxWidth="120" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Group}" Header="Group" MinWidth="200" MaxWidth="360" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        ...
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Section}" Header="Setion" MinWidth="120" MaxWidth="120" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

Sorry for all the coding, I just want to give as much information as possible. :) Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This has nothing to do with WPF or the datagrid, it's a WCF error. Did you `See server logs for more details.` ?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am new to WCF, but how can I check the server logs?

Comment: Your query in `GetLastQuote` can be easily simplified. Use `db.Quotes.LastOrDefault();` instead.